# Text-based package manager GUI for CentOS

Tags: centos, terminal, package-management, console, graphical-user-interface

I come from Debian Linux. In that OS I used `aptitude` for a neat ncurses text-based GUI package manager. What exists for **CentOS** that is the same?

Comment: Text based or GUI? It's either one or the other.

Comment: I think he's using the term "GUI" to apply to any menu-based system.  ncurses certainly restricts it to the realm of the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yum:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/

I don't know of an ncurses front for it but there is "Yum Extender" (yumex) which is a full GUI front-end to yum.

Hope that helps.